# Ember Router - Back button with nested dynamic segments not working

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble with the Ember router and nested dynamic segments.  The app works well navigating into the nested routes, but the back button fails despite updating the url correctly.  So I can navigate to 'sectionB/batch/3/artwork/1' and everything works correctly, but when the back button takes you to 'sectionB/batch/3' nothing updates and the artwork view remains.

Here's a jsfiddle with the app -

http://jsfiddle.net/aloshea/xYgeg/

If I go type the url 'sectionB/batch/3' directly into the browser, the deserialize function works correctly, so I feel this is very close to working.  Anyone out there had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property `location: 'hash'` in your router, like the following:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  location: 'hash',
  //your code
```

}

Comment: I believe the default is hash

Comment: there is this option location: 'history' too

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by moving the dynamic segment of batch into a 'show' route.  For some reason you lose batch id from the url when inside artwork, but the history works as expected so this is not a problem.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aloshea/Yb8cn/